# gridview auto suggestin through database when i write text in textbox without taking button

Tags: asp.net, gridview, autosuggest

i want to create program like when i write in the `textbox` some text or string the `gridview` automatically display the related data which is available in the database

i have created program but when i input some string like 'p' then i have to press tab button to get data and its displays also
but i want to do automatic filter when user write something its display the related data into the gridview

Comment: for which plattform? Android? JSP? QT? Please add more information and what have you tried. Show some code!

Comment: Asp.net platform please help me....